# How do you pass an array as an argument to a contract *constructor* using Truffle deployment script

Tags: contract-development, truffle, truffle-migration

I need to pass array as argument to contract constructor using truffle deployment script.

My contract code looks like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract ArrayArgument {
    uint[] public arrsv;

    constructor(uint[] memory arr) public {
        for(uint i=0; i< arr.length; i++)
        {
            arrsv[i] = arr[i];
        }
    }

    function fetcharrayindexvalue(uint index) public view returns (uint)
    {
        return arrsv[index];
    }
}
```

My deployment script looks like this:

```
var ArrayArgument = artifacts.require("ArrayArgument");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(ArrayArgument, [10, 12, 35]);
};
```

But when I try to migrate my contract, I get the following error:

```
Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"ArrayArgument" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:
   * Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
   * Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
   * Adding reason strings to your assert statements.

  at C:\Users\Saurab Marjara\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-deployer\src\deployment.js:364:1
  at <anonymous>
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
Truffle v5.0.8 (core: 5.0.8)
Node v8.10.0
```

How do I pass an array argument to a contract constructor from the deployment script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `"ArrayArgument" hit an invalid opcode while deploying` error is due to a problem which occurs **during runtime** (i.e., not because of how you pass the array to the constructor).

The problem is that the initial length of the dynamic array `uint[] public arrsv` is 0.

So you cannot access (neither read nor write) elements in this array via `arrsv[i]`.

---

Change this:

```
arrsv[i] = arr[i];
```

To this:

```
arrsv.push(arr[i]);
```

Comment: thank you so much. I was really at my wit's end regarding this..... again thank you.

Comment: @saurabmarjara: You're welcome. What does `wit's end` mean?

Comment: :) wit's end means not knowing what to do next